# Consuming REST Service in Delphi 2005

Tags: delphi, rest

Can someone please provide a simple example of how to consume a REST service using Delphi 2005?

The service appears to provide both XML and JSON, so I haven't decided which one to use.

Comment: You must provide more information about the rest service which you want to consume, like the data exchange format (json,xml).

Comment: This is my first foray into REST and I am not sure which one to use.  The service appears to provide either format.

Comment: Ok, then try these videos of marco cantu http://www.embarcadero-info.com/in_action/radstudio/rest.html (don't worry by the delphi 2010 title, the components used in the samles works in delphi 2005 too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Head to [Delphi REST Clients Collection](http://ajax.marcocantu.com/delphirest/default.htm) by Marco Cantù where you can find lots of code on the topic.

It's good for you. I wish you good luck

Comment: Thank you both, excellent resources!